# Which would be more appropriate: redirecting users on a subdomain to go to my shop or stay in the same domain

Tags: layout

I am currently designing my portfolio and I want to integrate my shop into it but I'm quite not sure if it would work with my idea. My idea is to build my portfolio and have a button where it says "Visit my shop" then they'll be redirected on another window to my shop on a sub-domain and on a different website design. Which do you guys think works best? Having them redirected on a sub-domain or having them stay on the same domain and have my shop incorporated in the same domain? I have attached a wire-frame of my portfolio so you'll kinda get where I'm getting at. I haven't finished the design yet because I am not sure if my idea will work. Any help is very much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Forget the subdomain, you get just problems for about nothing. Make a nice URL instead.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say go for a sub domain. by doing this it'll clearly differentiate the different part of your website and will refocus users from viewing/getting inspired mode into shopping mode. have seen this practice across some commercial websites.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! And yes, I've thought of that too. I'm just quite caught in between because I'm not sure if by doing so will have my shop earn a lot of visitors and also, my shop's not gonna be something like Themeforest or so. It's just going to be a personal shop where I get to put my stuff in. Thanks for your answer though! I would still love to hear what others think! :) Wish I could vote up your answer!

Comment: As this is about UX, I agree. Although you have to be careful in terms of SEO (domain trust). And @CheeseCake, go ahead, you can vote up the answer now ;-)

Comment: Thank you @msparer. Okay, I'm a noob at SEO. Lol. Would you mind explaining why should I be careful?

Comment: @CheeseCake in a nutshell, search engines treat each (sub)domain separately. So gaining reputation/trust with your www domain won't help you building trust with your subdomain. But if you're providing great content on both sites it won't be much of a problem I suppose.